# Cant solve this differential equation using laplace transforms

Tags: laplace-transform

$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
 y''(t) &=& x(t) - 2y(t)\\
 x''(t) &=& - 2x(t) + y(t)
\end{array}\right.$$
$y(0)=1,\;x(0)=1,\; y'(0) = \sqrt3,\; x'(0) = -\sqrt3$.

I am trying to solve this differential system using laplace transforms but the terms make it very hard to calculate it. I got 
$$
x = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{s^3 - \sqrt{3} s^2 + 3s - \sqrt{3}}{(s^2+2)^2 - 1} \right\}
$$ 
But that looks insanely difficult to find the laplace inverse. Is there anyway to make this simpler to do by hand?

Comment: I got that by taking laplace transforms of both those equations, and multiplying the second one by (s^2+2) and then adding them up, and solving for x.

Comment: Nope they are continious variables

Comment: Wait i will edit it a bit better

Comment: I think that is solved using a 4d vector $X = (x, y, x', y')$ then putting up the system $X' = A X$.

Comment: There, they x and y are both functions of t

Comment: And $X = X(0) e^{At}$ or similiar.

Comment: I dont quite understand you want me to put the system in a matrix?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to solve the equations, albeit this has nothing to do with Laplace transformation. :-)

Comment: Or type `x'' = y -2 x, y'' = x - 2y, y(0)=1,x(0)=1, y'(0) = sqrt(3), x'(0) = -sqrt(3)` into the Wolfram Alpha query box. That computer algebra system is amazing.

Comment: Yes why not trying to solve using two matrices of order 2, of whom the first is the 0-matrix (as the derivates of order 2 do not depend on those of order 1)

Comment: Nah the denominator is missing on the first half

Comment: (s^3-sqrt(3)*s^2+3s-sqrt(3))/((s^2+2)^2-1)

Comment: That looks so beautiful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $s^3-\sqrt3s^2+3s-\sqrt3=(s^2+1)(s-\sqrt3)+2s$ and that $(s^2+2)^2-1=(s^2+1)(s^2+3)$. Thus
$$x=\mathcal L^{-1}\left(\frac{s-\sqrt3}{s^2+3}+\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{s}{s^2+3}\right).$$
(I have used a decomposition into simple elements.)
It is a simple inversion, yielding
$$x(t)=\cos(t)-\sin(t\sqrt3).$$

Comment: Uhhh...check your work.  I don't think that factorization is right.

Comment: @baddin. You're welcome. Note that any rational function where the degree of the numerator is lower than the degree of the denominator has an elementary Laplace inverse. One should always decompose the rational function into simple elements.

Comment: @RonGordon. Yes you are right. Edit on progress... done

Answer (score 1):

Taking the LT of both equations and initial values yields

$$(s^2+2) Y(s)-X(s) = s+\sqrt{3}$$
$$(s^2+2) X(s)-Y(s) = s-\sqrt{3}$$

Solution yields

$$X(s) = \frac{s}{s^2+1} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{s^2+3} $$
$$Y(s) = \frac{s}{s^2+1} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{s^2+3} $$

Inversion of these, individually, yields

$$x(t) = \cos{t} - \sin{\sqrt{3} t}$$
$$y(t) = \cos{t} + \sin{\sqrt{3} t}$$

Plugging this solution into the original equation yields agreement.

**ADDENDUM**

The algebra involved in the solution is a little tricky.  To get $Y$, multiply both sides of the first equation by $s^2+2$ and add to the second equation to get

$$\left [ (s^2+2)^2-1\right ] Y(s) = (s^2+2) (s+\sqrt{3}) + s-\sqrt{3} = s(s^2+3) + \sqrt{3} (s^2+1)$$

Note that $(s^2+2)^2-1 = (s^2+1) (s^2+3)$.  Dividing through yields the solution.

To get $X$, multiply the second equation through by $s^2+2$ and add to the first equation.  The manipulations are virtually identical.

Comment: How did you get from the LT of both equations to the solution of laplace of each function in this form?

Comment: Looks like plain algebraic solution.

Comment: @baddin: if it is the algebra you are having a tough time with, I will outline.

Comment: Yes it is the algebra